# $g''(t_0)$ where $g(t) = f(t, 1-t) , t_0 = 0$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces

Let *z = f(x,y)* be a differentiable function such that $\frac{∂f}{∂x}$ (0,1) *= -1*  ,$\frac{∂f}{∂y}$ (0,1) *= 2*  , $\frac{∂^2f}{∂x^2}$ (0,1) *= 2* , $\frac{∂^2f}{∂x∂y}$ (0,1) *= -1* , $\frac{∂^2f}{∂y^2}$ (0,1) *= 0*.  Find the second derivative $g''(t_0)$ where:

a. $g(t) = f(t, 1-t) , t_0 = 0$

b. $g(t) = f(1-t^2, cos(t-1)) , t_0 = 1$

This is what I think:

for a. I have $g'(0) = \frac{∂f}{∂x} (0,1) + \frac{∂f}{∂y} (0,1) *(-1) = -3$. 
   Now, $g''(0) =0$

Is this correct? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider (a).  You've already done the first derivative using the chain rule;
\begin{align}
  g'(t) = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(t, 1-t) - \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(t,1-t)
\end{align}
now take another derivative using this result by applying the chain rule to each term on the right hand side;
\begin{align}
  g''(t) = \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(t,1-t) - \frac{\partial^2f}{\partial y\partial x}(t,1-t) - \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y}(t,1-t) + \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2}(t,1-t)
\end{align}
and plug in the desired value of $t$.  Now do a similar thing for (b).

Comment: Now I get it, but why do they give me the values of $\frac{∂f}{∂x} (0,1)$ and $\frac{∂f}{∂y} (0,1)$?

Comment: @user129120 Your guess is as good as mine.